# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. - login page

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I trying to make a login page and have approached this error. I am at the moment working on making the program check a database file for the user ID that they created so they can be logged in but I get this error:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

I can't seem to get it to work after a few hours so I have come here for help.

The function that is causing the problem is: `login_verify()`
The line that is causing the error has been marked with a comment 
The code that is shown is only the snippet with the error.

**Picture of the error:**

[image]

**Picture of the database:**

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

def login_verify(): 

   global ID

   with sqlite3.connect('Form.db')as db:

      cursor=db.cursor()
      finduser=('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = ?')
      cursor.execute(finduser,(ID,)) #line causing error


   if cursor.fetchall():
      print('hello')

   else:
      print('test')


def database():

   name1=Fullname.get()
   email=Email.get()
   gender=Gender.get()
   country=c.get()

   iD=ID.get()

   conn = sqlite3.connect('Form.db')

   with conn:
      cursor=conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Fullname TEXT,Email TEXT,Gender TEXT,country TEXT, ID TEXT)')
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (FullName,Email,Gender,country,ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',(name1,email,gender,country,iD))
   conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells that the type of `ID` is unsupported.
You defined `ID = IntVar()` so try to use the `get` method:

```
cursor.execute(finduser,(ID.get(),))
```